# How do fish tank stands take the weight?

Tags: wooden-furniture

So I was wondering how they take the weight? I have one tank that is 125 litres (33g) and its on the fluval 125 stand which i know is made for the tank. But with the weight of the water and tank when full how does it handle this? Because the stand has no central support at all? Its on support at the left and right side. [image: pulled the picture from online but you see what I mean]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the load (weight) is distributed to the sides and the 5 cross members that are visible in the picture share the job of keeping the stand square(lateral support). The bottom one and the one in the shade doing the brunt of that job. The top deck is to transfer the weight to the sides and the top illuminated cross member keeps it from sagging as does the large shaded cross member.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean lol, is it safe is all I want to know? Do the sides take most of the weight? The 2 larger peices at either side?

Comment: Sorry, yes it seems like a fairly good design and the sides take all the weight.

Comment: A glass fishtank with a rimmed edge doesn't even need the whole bottom supported by the top deck, all the weight rests on the perimeter of the tank. Acrylic tanks do need that support across the whole bottom, though.